# Get Count of a Zip folder + match size Powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to get Count of a zip folder that has for example 30 CSV files
The test folder has 30 csv files

```
$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem "$TEST\*.csv" | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo.count
```

All 30 csv files will be compressed into a zip folder = TESTZIP1.zip located inside of TEST folder.

If I try to run the following to measure how many files are inside of the compressed folder, I get 0 as answer

```
 $backUP = Get-ChildItem "$zipfiletest\TESTZIP1.zip\*.csv" | Measure-Object
 $backUP.count
```

Goal: able to Count() how many files are inside of zip folder, and if zip folder has the same amount of files as TEST folder, sends an email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to count the files inside your zip-file, you can do it like this:

```
$ZipFile = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open("$zipfiletest\TESTZIP1.zip",[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Read)
$ZipFile.Entries.count
$ZipFile.Dispose()
```

If you want to check anything else inside the zip file, you can easily explore the other parameters of the $ZipFile variable

Comment: Make sure you call `$ZipFile.Dispose()` after getting the count or it will stay locked.

Comment: Thanks, i did something different -

Comment: How could i match  the csv files located on folder A , with the zip files that contains all the csv files from folder A. If they match, then it gets zip otherwise rerun the code

Comment: The $ZipFile variable holds information on csv file names and actual size. You can compare that to the files you have in Folder A

Comment: How could I set up in a way if numbers match or if the numbers do not match , between folder A and ZIP file, then sends an ALERT, or vice versa. I already have the email setup .

Comment: ```if ($directoryInfo.count -eq $ZipFile.Entries.count){<code for same amount of files in folder and zipfile>} else {<code for different amount of files in folder and zipfile (send mail)>}```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileToCheck = Get-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path "C:\Users\" -ChildPath test.zip) - ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$ZipFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $fileToCheck -Recurse -Filter '*.zip'
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

$Results = foreach( $fileToCheck in $ZipFiles ){
  $DATCount = $Shell.NameSpace($fileToCheck.FullName).Items() |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\.dat$' } |
    Measure-Object |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty count
```